# Firebase Cloud Functions Best Practice?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a few questions regarding Firebase Cloud Function best practices, any insight and advice is highly appriciated!

1. Where is the best place to initialize the admin SDK, as you can only do this once, should you do it in a separate file, initialize the services you need (like Firestore and functions) and export them, or to initialize the admin SDK at root, index.ts?
2. If you have multiple task related to a single event, should you trigger multiple cloud function to handle different tasks for the same event, or tigger one cloud function for the event which handles multiple tasks. For example if you have a document create event where you want to update some user setting, send out an email, write data to a different document.
3. Setting region for where the cloud functions are deployed, should you take the time and select a region closest to your user for each individual function? (I have not seen option to set it globally)

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

There is no "better way" to do these things than what is explicitly described in the official documentation, but I will try to help you with tips that have worked for me, considering the topics of your question (note that I use javascript to develop on the Cloud Functions, not Typescript):

1. Initializing the admin SDK from an organized and dedicated directory can be a good idea: Do it and then import it to your index.js file. Why? This will keep your index.js file smaller, cleaner and focused on your Cloud Functions's exports. Bonus: I like to define the admin SDK as a global right after importing it on index.js. Handling globals in a smart way can improve your app performance and other benefits.

**But be careful: globals are shared across your Cloud Function execution (more info about it below)**

2. You should remember when developing on Cloud Functions: each function is isolated from each other and the same function container can be reused for new incoming requests; the first execution of a Cloud Function after a "standby" will take some extra time - it is called "cold start". If you are not doing asynchronous work, you'll be probably fine doing everything on the same function - you are ~already there. Complete Express.js apps, server-side rendered apps (with Nuxt, for example) and much more complex stuff can be implemented with a single function.

**You should watch this Firebase YouTube channel series focused on Cloud Functions: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DYfP-UIKxH0&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLkPZHe41m4jfAxUi0JjLgSM**

3. Selecting a region for Firebase can make your users experiences much much better... or not. Be sure to check the availability of all the Firebase products used by your app on each region, or the result could be the opposite while they are ~talking to each other:

> When selecting what regions to run your functions in, your primary
> considerations should be latency and availability. You can generally
> select regions close to your users, but you should also consider the
> location of the other products and services that your app uses. Using
> services across multiple regions can affect your app's latency, as
> well as pricing. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations